# jQuery code to close popup text after a certain time or when user click anywhere in screen

Tags: html, jquery, popup

HTML:

```
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Info"/>
 <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

You can see my work: https://jsfiddle.net/t2ywx6ng/4/

I want the popup to be closed when user click anywhere on the screen or otherwise after a specific time. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a timer for that, that gets started after the document is readily loaded ;)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Wait 5000 milli seconds then call call the function to close the pop-up;
    setTimeout(myFunction, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First load `JQuery` in your script (of course, you don't have to use a CDN. You can also [download JQuery](https://jquery.com/download/))

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
```

Then, you can add a `hide` option to make things easy to see and understand.

```
.popup .hide {
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
```

Now, you can check if the user clicked anywhere in the screen and hide the popup like doing so:

```
$(window).click(function() {
    popup.classList.toggle("hide");
});
```

If the user clicks on the button itself it won't close(optinal)

```
$('.popup').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

And for the time you can wait when the doccuemnt is loaded and set a timer to when to close the popup (in this example it's 5 seconds)

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){ popup.classList.toggle("hide"); }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Well you are using `CDN` anyway. Loading a library from an external source. What does that means ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping It's fine. You can instead download the JQuery code and include it in your code. The CDN basically is loading it for you from the internet. Download JQuery - https://jquery.com/download/

Comment: Well! You are loading the `scripts` it over the internet.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Yeah, what is the problem?

Comment: Its not good to have jQuery `downloaded` in your server too. Because if any function is deprecated or their a new function. You will downloading the Jquery library again and uploading it back to your server.

Comment: The problem is you do not need to mentioned this in your answer `(of course, you don't have to use a CDN)`  BECAUSE you are using a CDN and added ` jQuery script` via CDN

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I meant that the asker can download it too. I linked it in the comments....

Comment: If the OP can donwload then do not add this in your answer `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`  because this is CDN.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping It's really not crucial.... Maybe she doesn't know how... I'll also add the link to download the JQuery code in the question.